# How to import data like the SQLITE3 .import command in a c application?

Tags: sqlite

I know that the .import command is for the Sqlite3 shell and not for the C API used in my program and that the db may be created and populated before I connect it from my application. However I would like to create a Sqlite db in my program and import data into one of its tables from a text file (eg. data.txt in Windows).
Is there a way to do this or do I have to code something similar to the .import command in my program?

Answer (score 0):

You must either

- incude the SQLite statements as strings in your application and use [`sqlite3_exec`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) on the string(s)
- or code something similar to the `.import` command

Since the sqlite.c shell program is public domain, you may simply copy the `.import` code into your application.